# Crashlytics Fabric : Failed to execute task

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've been having an issue and I don't know how to fix it.

My project use crashlytics, but it's always crash and not sent report. I have a TimeoutException:

```
08-25 03:04:31.876    2856-2856/connectivit.app E/Fabric﹕ Failed to execute task.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
--------- beginning of crash
08-25 03:04:31.876    2856-2856/connectivit.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: connectivit.app, PID: 2856
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{connectivit.app/connectivit.app.Activity.Main.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a crash
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a crash
        at connectivit.app.Activity.Main.MainActivity.initTabs(MainActivity.java:117)
        at connectivit.app.Activity.Main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**EDIT**

My build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'android.keystore'
            storeFile file('/Users/jordan/android.keystore.jks')
            storePassword ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('/Users/jordan/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “com.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName '1'

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet false
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //--- Android
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    //--- Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Crashlytics initialization :

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d("Ez", "Release mode. Crashlytics enable");
        //Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    } else {
        Log.d("Ez", "Debug mode. Crashlytics disable");
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle and your Crashlitycs initializiation.

Comment: You can find my build.gradle and my crashlitycs initialization in my previous post

Comment: Have you tried throwing the runtime exception at a different time in the lifecycle? for example onResume in your first Activity

Comment: Yes I've tried OnCreate, OnResume, OnPause in my first Activity.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the `TimeoutException` by adding the following to my `build.gradle`

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = true
```

Or if you have several extensions already:

```
ext {
    ...
    enableCrashlytics = true
}
```

You can put it in your application's `build.gradle`.

Comment: where should I add them?

Comment: which build.gradle?

Comment: Putting it into the app's build.gradle fixed it for me

Comment: This did not resolve the issue in the Coinverse app. Here is the [open-source code](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) and a related [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010884/crash-with-proguard-using-firebase-libraries).

Comment: For KTS build.gradle - ext.set("enableCrashlytics", true)

Answer (score 8):

This issue drove me crazy still in 2019, but I think I finally figured out, what did the exception cause.

I followed all the setup instructions given in the [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=2&platform=android#nav-buttons-1), but when I tested my solution I didn't get any report on Firebase Crashlytics admin, because of the TimeoutException.

The reason was in my case, that I triggered the Exception in my main activity's onCreate() or onResume() methods.
When I let my app at the first start just run without exception, then later I started to get the reports without any error, so I think it's important, that **at the first start the app shouldn't throw any exception in the hook methods**.

Hope my experience helped.

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue as well. I solved it simply by doing `Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart`

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Right after apply plugin section of your build.gradle put the ext solution

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

ext {
    enableCrashlytics = true
}

android { }
```

!Then do Invalidate cache and restart.
Also make sure you have `implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate answer within this post as this solution is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46170025/2253682).

Answer (score 1):

My solution is next:

1. Remove all old Fabric related code
2. Migrate fully app to Firebase. I use [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android&authuser=0) for that
3. My observation shows Crashlytic sends report next time app is launched and in case app crashes every time in `Application::onCreate` method you probably won't see any reporting in Firebase console.

How I test that:

1. Thrown test exception in `Application::onCreate` method
2. Commented that throwing and launch app again
3. Approximately in a minute I saw crash in Firebase console.

Hope it also helps you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, I solved it by installing android studio fabric plugin directly via Settings->Plugins android studio and let the plugin edit my code in gradle. 
You can see it done here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qvqr6vGzxIs

Answer (score 0):

> Check Your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, it contains duplicate container
> or written more than two times that's it.

Because, I had faced this problem while I accidentally wrote the same container twice.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here, you follow the google docs and it just doesn't work. 5 years ago Crashlytics used to be extremely solid. Sad to see this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some entries in AndroidManifest.xml that were not valid anymore. Java runtime couldn't find them, which caused the crash.

To be more precise, I was using a Facebook plugin that I removed but left some config entries in AndroiManifest.xml. After I removed them this error disappeared.

In your case, it could be something else in the AndroidManifest.

This is one of the possible causes. Each App is different.

Answer (score -4):

According to Crashlytics support guide :

> Make sure our SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDKs

So try to set `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` after all of your other sdk related initialization if any.
If no other sdk initialization there then try  to set it after your BuildConfig initialization.

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();  

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d("Ez", "Release mode. Crashlytics enable");
       //Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    } else {
        Log.d("Ez", "Debug mode. Crashlytics disable");
    }
   Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

   throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you've another library that cause this error. Try to remove it,

for example you can try

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Answer (score -4):

Cause the app may crash before Fabric can connect to its service.
Solution: just remove your throw Exception code and perform a fresh install.