# Firebase Crashlytics not sending crash report

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am using firebase in my app. I add Crashlytic to my app. when I run, I simulate an exception but Crashlytic never generate and send report in my firebase console. Below the exception I got.

```
04-03 17:10:35.731 12442-12477/com.package.app E/CrashlyticsCore: Tried to write a fatal exception while no session was open.
04-03 17:10:39.733 12442-12442/com.package.app E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:177)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:320)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:300)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
```

Even when I simulate crash from [Crashlytic get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) the app never crash

```
Button crashButton = new Button(this);
crashButton.setText("Crash!");
crashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(); // Force a crash
    }
});
addContentView(crashButton,
               new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and when I simulate my own app crash the report never generate and sent.

Gradle script project level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}

        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
```

Gradle build script app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    //..........some dependencies
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    //................. some dependencies
    //Crashlytics sdk dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: is your internet connected? seems like it's timing out

Comment: Yes connected to network. I run the app in my real device and it is connected.

Comment: you know what, maybe try a normal crash instead of the simulated one... try throwing an exception. Maybe the API call is glitchy. Also do make sure that you have setup crashlytics exactly according to the steps they asked

Comment: could you post your gradle files (both app and project level) as well as the place where you initialize crashalytics?

Comment: I made changes in my question with Crashlytic configuration. I also already enabled it in my firebase console. according to the documentation that is all we need to do to make it works.

Comment: I already simulate with my own exception but same output in my logcat. @Kushan

Comment: can you post your manifest?

Comment: also which build are you using? release or debug?

Comment: I am using debug build. Do I need to do some changes in the manifest? I did not make changes in my manifest. Please advise.

Comment: I doubt it's a problem, but this is not needed in your build file: `ext.enableCrashlytics = true`.  Also, if you have any Firebase or Google Play services libs in your dependencies that are not included in what you posted, they should be 11.8.0 not 12.0.0; for compatibility with FirebaseUI 3.2.2.

Comment: I am using 11.8.0 version. inside wich bloc do I need to put `ext.enableCrashlytics = true`  in gradle build script ? @BobSnyder

Comment: Crashlytics works for me without `ext.enableCrashlytics`.  It's not in the [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).  Why do you think it's needed?

Comment: I"ve added an answer under the following StackOverlow thread about a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197659/crashlytics-fabric-failed-to-execute-task/57795922#57795922

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have enabled notifications in fabric dashboard settings for the test crash that your are generating in you code.

after enabling , You will then get crash mails.

Comment: With firebase we do not need to deal with fabric website I think. I do not have account in fabric website.