# Failed to instantiate AndroidPlatform class using ProGuard

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, crashlytics

## Expect

It is expected for the *release* version of the Android app's build to run successfully when enabling `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` per the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?utm_source=android-studio#shrink-resources), Crashlytics, and Proguard.

## Observe

**The code for this issue may be found in the [open-sourced GitHub repository](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) for Coinverse.**

- The *release* version of the app crashes immediately when opened after being downloaded from Google Play.
- Without `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` the app runs as expected in production, and the app size goes from ~4mb to ~10mb.
- The error log suggests it is an issue with Firebase compatibility and recommends this StackOverflow post. - [What ProGuard configuration do I need for Firebase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android)
- There is a similar issue with ProGuard - [transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454128/transformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease-failed).

## Error

**Summary**

With Crashlytics enabled.

`Crashlytics Core: Failed to execute task`

Without Crashlytics enabled.

`Failed to instantiate AndroidPlatform class using ProGuard`

**Details**

```
2020-04-19 12:08:48.137 21704-21704/? E/app.coinverse: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-04-19 12:08:49.684 21704-21704/app.coinverse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.coinverse, PID: 21704
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application app.coinverse.App: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate AndroidPlatform class.  Using ProGuard?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6465)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate AndroidPlatform class.  Using ProGuard?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android
        at d.b.a.d.a.a(:69)
        at d.b.a.a.a(:974)
        at app.coinverse.j.a.<init>(:44)
        at app.coinverse.j.b.a(:29)
        at app.coinverse.j.b.get(:21)
        at app.coinverse.j.b.get(:8)
        at e.b.b.get(:47)
        at app.coinverse.i.d.a(:107)
        at app.coinverse.App.onCreate(:18)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: d.b.a.c.a.<init> [class android.content.Context]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at d.b.a.d.a.a(:62)
        at d.b.a.a.a(:974) 
        at app.coinverse.j.a.<init>(:44) 
        at app.coinverse.j.b.a(:29) 
        at app.coinverse.j.b.get(:21) 
        at app.coinverse.j.b.get(:8) 
        at e.b.b.get(:47) 
        at app.coinverse.i.d.a(:107) 
        at app.coinverse.App.onCreate(:18) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

## Implement

*build.gradle (:app)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.coinverse"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 57
        versionName "0.57"
        kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets { androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString()) }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro',
                    'proguard.cfg'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            debuggable true
        }
        open {
            initWith debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".open"
        }
    }
    compileOptions { targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

    dataBinding.enabled = true

    testOptions { unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = '2.2.0'
    def lifecycle_test_version = '2.1.0'
    def nav_version = '2.2.1'
    def play_services_version = '17.0.0'
    def exoplayer_version = '2.11.1'
    def room_version = '2.2.5'
    def glide_version = '4.11.0'
    def mopub_version = '5.12.0'
    def junit_version = '5.5.1'
    def test_rules_core_version = '1.2.0'
    def fragment_version = '1.2.4'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.2"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$play_services_version"
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
    implementation("com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:$mopub_version") { transitive = true }
    implementation("com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-video:$mopub_version") { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:facebookaudiencenetwork:5.8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:ads:12.3.0'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:flurry:12.0.3.1'

    // Testing

    // Local Unit
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3"
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.13.2'
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_test_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2"

    // AndroidX - JVM
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.1"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$test_rules_core_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$test_rules_core_version"
}
```

*build.gradle (android)*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.5.1.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*App.kt*

**The release version of the app is crashing when attempting to initialize the *FirebaseHelper.kt* class.**

```kotlin
class App : Application() {
    val component = DaggerComponent.builder()
            .utilsModule(UtilsModule(this))
            .build()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Here is where the crash occurs.
        component.firebaseHelper()
        MoPub.initializeSdk(this, SdkConfiguration.Builder(AD_UNIT_ID).build(), initSdkListener())
    }

    private fun initSdkListener() = SdkInitializationListener { /* MoPub SDK initialized.*/ }
}
```

*FirebaseHelper.kt*

```kotlin
@Singleton
class FirebaseHelper @Inject constructor(context: Context) {
    private val LOG_TAG = FirebaseHelper::class.java.simpleName

    init {
        if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == open.name) {
            var openSharedStatus = false
            FirebaseApp.getApps(context).map { app ->
                if (app.name.equals(open.name))
                    openSharedStatus = true
            }
            if (!openSharedStatus)
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
                        context,
                        FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                                .setApplicationId(APP_ID_OPEN_SHARED)
                                .setApiKey(APP_API_KEY_OPEN_SHARED)
                                .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL_OPEN_SHARED)
                                .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID_OPEN_SHARED)
                                .setStorageBucket(STORAGE_BUCKET_OPEN_SHARED)
                                .build(),
                        open.name)
        }
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(context)
        initializeRemoteConfig()
    }

    private fun initializeRemoteConfig() {
        val firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
        firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().build())
        firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
        val cacheExpiration = 3600L
        try {
            firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        } catch (exception: FirebaseRemoteConfigException) {
            Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, LOG_TAG, "initializeRemoteConfig: ${exception.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

## Attempt Solutions

**1. Remove Crashlytics.**

A. Remove all instances of `Crashlytics.log(...)`

B. Remove Fabric plugin and Crashlytics library in *build.gradle (:app)*

```
// apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

...
// implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

C. Remove Fabric from *build.gradle (android)*

```
 repositories {
    ...
    // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
 dependencies {
     ...
     // classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
 }
```

**2. Handle models' serialization/deserialization to/from Firestore's database with Proguard.**

A. [Add *proguard.cfg* rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard)

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.analytics.models.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.analytics.models.ContentAction.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.analytics.models.UserAction.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.analytics.models.UserActionCount.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.feed.models.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.feed.models.FeedViewState.** {
 *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.feed.models.FeedViewState.Content.** {
 *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.feed.models.FeedViewState.ContentToPlay.** {
 *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.feed.models.FeedViewState.ContentPlayer.** {
 *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.ExchangeOrderData.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.ExchangeOrdersDataPoints.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.MaximumPercentPriceDifference.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.Order.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.PercentDifference.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.PriceGraphData.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.PriceGraphXAndYConstraints.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.priceGraph.models.PricePair.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.user.models.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.user.models.User.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class app.coinverse.utils.** {
  *;
}
# If Enums are used in the database, use 'ADB Clear App Data and Restart', and then re-run.
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```

B. Define models' [no-argument constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37874665/2253682). This should not be required for models that already have default values defined in the `data class` constructor. However, there is an error without explicitly defining the no-argument constructor, "*[users does not define no argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706601/users-does-not-define-no-argument-constructor)"*.

C. Handle Enums by [annotating enum names with `@SerializedName`](https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/gson-will-crash-at-enum-fields-in-custom-class-with-proguard-bbcf5ad1b623) and [adding the Proguard rule above to keep enumerations' members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167048/2253682). Only one of these implementations should be required.

**3. [Add *proguard.cfg* rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26274623/2253682) for Firebase.**

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

# Only necessary if you downloaded the SDK jar directly instead of from maven.
-keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

**4. [Add `pro-guard-rules-release.txt`](https://proandroiddev.com/what-are-you-keeping-from-me-44ece21f4631)**

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.txt'
testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-test.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and fully migrating from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics fixed the issue for me: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android&authuser=0

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is promising to hear @Tudor S! I will report back once I have implemented the migration to the Crashlytics beta to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I followed the documentation to install _[Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android)_ and confirmed it is working as expected in the Firebase console. Unfortunately, the Proguard issue above persists. The next step is to create a basic sample app to reproduce the issue in order to file an issue with the Android team.